# Get Resource by Name

Tags: android

Hy!

I have in my /values/strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="error418">Bad Request</string>
    <string name="error404">Not Found</string>
    ......
</resources>
```

the same in /values-de/strings.xml

Now i want to get the error messages by the string "error418".

I only found context.getString(int ...).

How to get the error message by code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get resource id dynamically, according to error code for example, you need to use [getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

e.g.

```
String err_code = ...;
int strId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("error" + err_code, "string", "packagename");
if (strId != 0)
    Toast.maketext(context, context.getString(strId), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
else 
    Toast.maketext(context, "Unknown error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```