# Accessing resources using getField

Tags: android

I am receiving an exception when I try to get the field of a resource in an Android application. It seems like correct way of accessing a drawable id. Any suggestions what could be wrong?

```
04-09 22:45:59.816: W/System.err(5014): java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: lumiere
```

In my res/drawable folder I have "lumiere.jpg". From R.java:

```
public static final class drawable {
    [...]
    public static final int lumiere=0x7f02000a;
```

method call:

```
Class c = R.drawable.class;
field = c.getField(name);
i = new Integer(field.getInt(null));
```

I don't think this matters, being a static class method call, but just in case it does - the above code is in a plain Java class, not an Activity. Just thought I'd mention since access to resources seems restricted outside of Activities.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you meant to use `c.getDeclaredField(name)`. Also (and this might be the more "correct" way to do it), you can use the `Resources` object to get the ID when you have the name. See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317301/get-resource-by-name).

Comment: I did try using that method as well, no dice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide class's object when calling **getInt** method:

```
    Integer i = null;       

    try {
        Class c = R.drawable.class;
        Field field = c.getField(name);
        if(field != null){
            i = new Integer(field.getInt(c));  //provide 'c' in getInt
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Read [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.lang.reflect/FieldgetIntObjectobj.htm) post

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that's not it.

You cannot in fact use this method to access resources from a plain Java class.

Comment: isn't it what more or less you are doing to get the value...?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Maybe my above statement was badly worded. The code in my post works if it's placed in an Activity class, but not in a standard Java class. I assume this is due to lack of context.

Comment: @Waqas: Since the field in question is static, you don't need to provide an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it appears that you in fact cannot use this to access resources contained in R.java file from a plain Java class. When I copied the code into a class that is an Activity, it did not throw an exception and returned a value.

Comment: Interesting. Different classloaders?